# Добавление input компоненты

Tags: angular, material-design

Сделал отдельную integer компоненту (ввод только целых чисел), но когда вставляю её, input не отображается
Вот так работает без компоненты:

```
<ng-container>
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
           [(ngModel)]="row.data[header.dataProperty].data"
           [name]="indi + '_' + header.dataProperty"
           (keypress)="onIntNumberKeyPress($event, row, header.dataProperty)"/>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

[image: есть строка ввода]

А так почему-то строка ввода не отображается:

```
<ng-container>
    <app-integer [row]="row" [header]="header" [indi]="indi"></app-integer>
</ng-container>
```

код app-ingteger

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
           [(ngModel)]="row.data[header.dataProperty].data"
           [name]="indi + '_' + header.dataProperty"
           (keypress)="onIntNumberKeyPress($event, row, header.dataProperty)"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[image: нет строки ввода]

В чём ошибка?

Comment: `<input` не должен заканчиваться на `/>`, надо просто `>`

Comment: спасибо, но не изменило ситуацию